# Firefox and IE looks different in Chrome

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, css-float

The styling I wanted to be is in Chrome but it looks different in Firefox and IE. All my fields are float to the right except the field "name". Is it about the floating?
 My Chrome:
[image]

My Firefox and IE:
[image]

There is a huge spaces besides "Status" and the header looks bigger in height too.

===CSS====

```
.column-name { margin: 2px; width: 40%; }
.column-priority { float: right; margin: 2px 12px; text-align: center; width: 100px;}
.column-severity { float: right; margin: 2px 12px; text-align: center; width: 100px;}
.column-status { float: right; margin: 2px; width: 100px;}
```

===HTML====

```
   <div class="results-header ">
        <div class="column-status" value="status">Status<span class="sort jive-icon-sml"></span></div>  
        <div class="column-severity" value="severity">Severity<span class="sort jive-icon-sml"></span></div>
        <div class="column-priority" value="priority">Priority<span class="sort jive-icon-sml jive-icon-arrow-generic-down"></span></div>   
        <div class="column-name"  value="name" >Name</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Looks like you're displaying tabular data, HTML has a tag for that.

Comment: You've asked 31 questions and accepted very few answers. Oh and before others point it out, where is your code?!

Comment: @PaoloBergantino: I am actually using a Jive platform and this is one of the widget in Jive.

Comment: @AshwinGanesh : I uploaded the parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm 99% sure it's because you need to tell which padding it has because that has higher priority in those browsers.

You might make a star rule

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
```

but again you need to post more code before I can tell you 100% what to do. btw if your uncertain about anything, related to browser compabtility see: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Answer (score 0):

always use css resets {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: 0;}
beacuse every browser has it's own margin, padding...